# Name a image upon save in user browser

Tags: php, image

i have created one image 
but problem is that when i save image from browser it saved as image.php but i want save it as custom name send from php

```
<?php

$my_img = imagecreatefromjpeg("images/photo.jpg");
$nw = 400;
$nh = 500;
$img2 = imagecreatetruecolor($nw, $nh);
imagecopyresampled($img2, $my_img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nw, $nh, imagesx($my_img), imagesy($my_img));

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
header('filename="Custome Name.jpeg"');
imagejpeg($img2,NULL,60);
imagedestroy($img2);
?>
```

when user will save image it must save as name sent from server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on bsdnoobz answer, try using *inline* value for *Content-Disposition* :

```
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="custom_name.jpg"');
```

instead of :

```
header('filename="Custome Name.jpeg"');
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line,

```
header('filename="Custome Name.jpeg"');
```

with

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="custom_name.jpg"');
```

Comment: if i do this it starts downloading

Comment: i want to display it on browser but when user save it,it must be save as custom name